# SCSS not mapping/compiling

Tags: html, css, sass

Finally got some time to explore web design a little, but now my scss code won't compile. Crap.

I first noticed that my changes weren't showing in live preview (Brackets). I then checked the corresponding .css file, where I could see that my changes weren't being mapped anymore. Crap.

I restarted everything (Brackets, Chrome, computer), but it still didn't work. I then copied my .scss code to clipboard, got rid of all the files (in this case home.scss, home.css, and home.css.map), and created a new home.scss-file. The mapper and .css files got generated, so that's still working. I then copied my code into the .scss file and saved, but nothing was mapped, once more. Don't know what's wrong here. Did anyone encounter this before? Everything was working just fine yesterday.

If it helps, here's the code:

home.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:200,300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href="../css/home.css">

</head>

<body>

    <div class="first">
        <img src="../images/HN_LogoWhite.svg" />
    </div>
    <div class="second">
        <section>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur voluptatibus sed iusto quaerat nesciunt eius incidunt saepe quam, unde quisquam nobis maiores similique at illo soluta, iure ipsum! Minima, possimus?</section>
        <section>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi, placeat ducimus quisquam, ullam quae temporibus esse fugiat nostrum quaerat eos facilis, excepturi labore laboriosam molestiae. Error libero ea saepe officiis.</section>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

home.scss

```
@import 'fontsAndColors';

/* Setting frame */

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    font-family: $main_font;
}

body {
    background-color: $hn_white;
    margin: 0;
}

.first {
    background-image: url('../images/TopUnderwater.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;

    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    img {
        width: 20%;
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: auto;
    }
}



.second {
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: $hn_green;
    padding: 5%;
    section {
        top: 10%;
        width: 30%;
        margin: 10%;
        padding: 10%;
        float: left;
        display: block;
        border: solid 1em $hn_green;
        position: relative;

        overflow:hidden;
    }
}
```

_fontsAndColors.scss

```
$hn_green: #6ca66b;
$hn_blue: #3398cc;
$hn_white: #ffffff;
$main_font: font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;

@mixin hn_bg_gr1($col1, $col2) {
    background: $col1;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, $col1, $col2); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom right, $col1, $col2); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom right, $col1, $col2); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, $col1, $col2); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
}

@mixin hn_bg_gr2($col1, $col2) {
    background: $col1; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient($col1, $col2); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient($col1, $col2); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient($col1, $col2); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient($col1, $col2); /* Standard syntax */

}
```

and, strangely, home.css.map

```
{
  "version": 3,
  "file": "home.css",
  "sources": [
    "home.scss",
    "_fontsAndColors.scss"
  ],
  "mappings": "",
  "names": []
}
```

Probably has nothing to do with it, but problems started shortly after I added the Oswald font from Google Fonts.

Thanks!

Comment: Try $main_font:  'Oswald', sans-serif; or $main_font: "font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif";

Comment: Yeah, that was definitely a mistake :) Didn't work straight away, but fiddled a little more and the mapper woke up again. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

All good, looks like a made a stupid mistake by stating this in the _fontsAndColors-file: $main_font: font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;

That caused a syntax error. font-family: font-family: ...

Thanks jseezo!